# Small deck on brick foundation

Tags: deck

I have an existing 4x3m (~13'2 x 9'11 ft) brick foundation that I want to use as a base for a small deck. The wall width is 25cm (~10in).

According to span tables I think I could just use 150x45 (~2x6) joists on top of it but it would end up with a deck 20cm (~8in) above the ground (foundation is ~1in above the ground). So I'm looking for a way to make it lower.

I though I could mount joists inside the foundation but I'm not sure how I would attach those few boards at the ends - can boards be screwed to the foundation itself?

So my final idea is to use two 150x45 (~2x6) as bearers, mount them inside and than lay 90x35 (~3 1/2 x 1 3/8) on top of them and foundation. Can bearers be mounted to the wall or do they need actual posts?

I've used https://www.softwoods.com.au/build-deck-step/ to come up with the numbers.

Is this feasible? Maybe there are better ways to do it?

[image: Quick drawing to make it clearer]

Comment: How does this brick look? Is it reliable? In the US our standard ledger details look like [this](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-5-floors#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch05_SecR507.9.1.3). My instinct is to drill all the way through the wall and install hot dip galvanized threaded rods as the anchorages (digging to put a nut on the outside of the wall). Alternatively there are long lag shields and short lag shields, where the long ones are intended for cases like your brick. I'm skeptical of this sort of detail without knowing your brick standards, the condition of your wall, etc.

Comment: Is this your code: https://ncc.abcb.gov.au/editions/2019-a1/ncc-2019-volume-two-amendment-1/part-310-ancillary-provisions-and-additional/p3.10.6?

Comment: I'm actually in Poland, I'll try to dig up the code. 

The brick looks reliable, few cracks here and there but very small (1-3mms). What's unusual is that bricks are laid on the side, perpendicular to wall lenght. In other words each brick is visible from inside and outside (not sure if I'm explaining that right). At least the top layer. I'll try to get some pictures and check if other layers look the same.

Comment: It seems there is no official code... At least no ledger details. According to few sources they are trying to make it happen but for now there are only few books published by an NGO, nothing online.

Comment: @Varius can you add pics of your wall?  Popham mentions a ledger, but I'm reading a freestanding wall from your post.  So it's not clear (at least to me) what you're dealing with.

Comment: @Huesmann I can get some pictures on Saturday but I've added a quick drawing of the foundation.

Comment: @Varius do you have any idea what's beneath the bricks?  Is there a concrete stem wall?  Might be worth doing a little digging.

Comment: I'll check it. I dug about 40-50cms to confirm that it's not just thin layer but didn't really check if it was brick or concrete.

Comment: The problem with using that Australian site is that their lumber grades don't match yours ("F7" looks like the grade, but I know nothing about Australian lumber). A quick search including "C16" found https://www.qualitydecking.co.uk/help/deck-planning/deck-sub-frame-design/ for me. Assuming that your lumber grades are C16 and/or C24, I would want a source like this that is calibrated for my grade of lumber. (I assume that your graded lumber uses that European system, but I know very little about lumber throughout Europe.)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've just checked and C16 is not really popular here, almost no one sells them. C24 is easily available.

Comment: I just looked at the link again. You saw that it also has C24 values tabulated, yeah?